# What does this crone expression mean?

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

Cron Expression :- `0 0 0 * * ?`

[CronTranslator](https://crontranslator.appspot.com/) interprets it as `at 00:00 on 0th of every month`  which starting of every month

[CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) interprets it as daily

After reading about  [crone expression](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html), to me cronMaker looks correct

Comment: And what has this to do with Java? You should study the "cron" documentation for that platform where this expression will be used though!

Comment: It's [_Cron_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and not "[Crone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crone)" ;)

Comment: @GhostCat - also what it has to do with spring? ;)

Comment: I guess he asks about Spring Scheduling, which uses slightly different expressions then UNIX crontab.

Comment: @Thomas i have corrected it

Comment: @GhostCat i was using in java program. But you are right its generic, i have removed it

Comment: Note that the original cron expression has minutes as the lowest unit, thus `0 0 0 * *` would be interpreted as the 0th of every month (minute 0, hour 0, day 0, ...). Schedulers like Quartz etc. extend that expression by seconds, so you'd get one more parameter and thus `0 0 0 ...` would be second 0, minute 0, hour 0 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring Scheduling / Quartz this will mean 00:00:00 every day. Traditional `crontab` does not use `?`, which could be the reason why CronTranslator interprets it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron the correct interpretation should be

minutes | hours | day of month | month | day of week | optional year

so your string refers to minute=0, hour=0, day_of_month=0, every month, every day of the week. The question mark may be interpreted in different ways, but usually means in your case every year.

As far as I can tell CroneTranslator is correct. But interpretation of this string might differ from framework to framework. It appears that CronMaker has an extra non-standard seconds field as first value.

However, your string is invalid, as **day of month** field accepts values from 1-31 -- your value of "0" doesn't make any sense.